# Filling JList with table

Tags: java, sql, swing, jlist

Does anyone have any good tutorial to fill a JList with table from sql like this query. The JList would get update every you create or delete a table.

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a class the load a List<String> from the database using this query. Then use this class from your swing class to get the list of strings, and populate the JList. Database-related code shouldn't be in the same classes as presentation-related code. Add a refresh button to your UI to re-execute the query and refresh the list. Or refresh it automatically every X seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, you do not need a tutorial :) Build your `JList` from the resuting list of elements using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#JList%28java.util.Vector%29) costructor.

Iterate on the query result cursor and fill a `Vector` with the elements you got from the DB. Then use the `Vector` as a the underlying data container (model) for building you `JList`:

```
Vector<String> elements = new Vector<String>();
while (query.next()) {
    // or whatever is appropriate
    elements.add(query.getString("name"));
}  
Jlist mylist = new Jlist(elements);
```

You should split the DB query code (model related) from the GUI building (view) to ease future maintainance and decouple the structure in a so-called MVC structure, but this is out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DefaultListModel` see this example :

```
    //......
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    String query = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'";
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next){
    listModel.addElement(rs.getObject("name"));// I think you want get this field
    }

    list.setModel(listModel);
```